# Unable to copy from Linux server to Mac client after 1.4.5 install

Tags: linux, mac, synergy, copy-paste

I installed version Synergy 1.4.5 on my Mac OS 10.7 (Lion) client, as part of a test to solve a much more complicated Synergy problem.

I now find:
* I can copy on the Mac and paste into Linux
* I can *not* copy from Linux and paste into Mac

I suspect, but I'm not certain, that the Synergy 1.4.5 GUI did something odd to my Mac client -- for example, "defaults read com.apple.loginwidow LoginHook" was incorrect after running the GUI.

"killall synergyc" followd by re-running synergyc does not fix the copy/paste problem.

I've removed the old synergyc and replaced it with the 1.3.8 version -- this does not restore the previous functionality.

Question: How can I restore my copy/paste from my Mac client to my Linux server?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/495/how-do-i-get-paste-to-work-on-mac-osx1068-client143-to-current-build) in the Synergy forums, the latest version of Synergy for the Mac that lets you copy from Linux and paste to the Mac is 1.3.1.

At a guess, I had 1.3.1 prior to my test of 1.4.5 and simply forgot that the latest stable Synergy simply does not have this crucial functionality.